# When can a spatial Manifold be deformed into another spatial manifold?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology

I'm reading a paper by Gaiotto, Kapustin, Seiberg, and Willett, titled "[Generalised Global Symmetries](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FJHEP02%282015%29172)" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3321281)). In section 3.1, paragraph 4 they write something to the order of:

If we have a $M^d$ spacetime manifold, and we take two spatial $M^{d-q-1}$ spatial sub-manifolds at times $t$, $t+\epsilon$, then the sub-manifold at time $t+\epsilon$ can be continuously deformed into a sub-manifold at time $t-\epsilon$ when $q>0$. This is why an operator $U_g(M^{d-q-1})$ on the sub-manifold $M^{d-q-1}$ must be abelian for q>0.

I understand that being able to deform the later sub-manifold into one that acts earlier than the other sub-manifold implies that an operator on the manifold must be abelian.

However I don't understand why it must be continuously deformable like stated above in the first place. Is there a proof/strong intuition to why this is true?

Apologies for the possible differences in language, I'm a physicist so I may not be using the terms and definitions precisely as they should be used.

Comment: MathSciNet has not heard of this paper ([search](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=Seiberg&co4=AND&pg5=TI&s5=Generalised+gauge+symmetries)), but Seiberg appears to write a lot about generalised *global* symmetries.  Is it possible that there's a typo?

Comment: @LSpice I'm so sorry I didn't remember the name exactly! I'll correct it right away. Grave mistake on my part.

Comment: OK, I have edited in a link to what seems to be the relevant article.

Comment: This is the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148. As best I can tell, they’re just referring to the usual Eckmann-Hilton argument. Note that they say that things change in the presence of nontrivial topology.

Comment: @AaronBergman I read through the wiki of Eckmann Hilton argument, not sure how it relates to this post. Are you saying that the deformation operation commutes with with the $U_g (M)$ operation due to them satisfying the Eckmann Hilton argument?

Comment: All I mean is that there’s enough room to move the submanifolds around. There’s no topology so just move the sub manifold out of the way and put it behind the other one.

Comment: @AaronBergman I guess that makes sense, and the reason why you can't do that in co dimension 1 sub manifolds is because they partition spacetime into two parts and act like a domain wall?

I guess this is good enough for now, thanks!